# create if suitescript have limits

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I want to create an if function in netsuite where the condition is
if the number is **less than** 2000000 then the value is T. if the number is **less than** 10000000 then the value is T. but **if the numbers are 2000000** the value is F

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
 *@author Test 
 */
define(['N/ui/serverWidget','N/record','N/runtime','N/search'],
    function (serverWidget, record, runtime, search){
        function beforeSubmit(context){
            try{
                var newRecord = context.newRecord;
                var type = context.type;
                if (type == context.UserEventType.CREATE || type == context.UserEventType.EDIT){
                    var subTotal = newRecord.getValue({
                        fieldId:'subtotal'
                    });
                if(subTotal < 2000000 || subTotal < 10000000){
                    newRecord.setValue({
                        fieldId: 'custbody_me_trans_code',
                        value: true,
                        ignoreFieldChange: true
                    });
                }
                else if(subTotal = 2000000){
                    newRecord.setValue({
                        fieldId: 'custbody_me_trans_code',
                        value: false,
                        ignoreFieldChange: true
                    });
                }
            }
        }
            catch (error){
                    log.debug("error", error);
                    throw "Something Error " + error;
            }
        }
        function afterSubmit(context) { 

            try {
                log.debug("After Submit")
            } 
            catch (error) {
                log.debug("error", error);
                throw "Something Error " + error;
            }
        }
        return {
            beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit,
            afterSubmit: afterSubmit
        };
    })
```

I made an if condition but 2000000 still becomes F because less than 10000000. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update the IF Condition like this -

```
if(subTotal < 10000000 && subTotal != 2000000) {
   newRecord.setValue({
       fieldId: 'custbody_me_trans_code',
       value: true,
       ignoreFieldChange: true
   });

   else if(subTotal = 2000000){
     newRecord.setValue({
       fieldId: 'custbody_me_trans_code',
       value: false,
       ignoreFieldChange: true
     });
   }
}
```

Let me know in canse of any issues in comments below.